# 3D plot of overlapping shapefiles in R

Tags: r, 3d, shapefile

I have a shapefile GIS layer with several overlapping paths. They consist of geodetics/shortest path calculations from several origins to one destination. I want to visualise these paths as either as lines or buffered polygons in 3D, as this is not possible in 2D. Ideally I would like to do this in R to maintain consistent color schemes and one workflow. ArcGIS Pro is able to do this - see example attached.

I have tried to achieve this with rayshader, but that does not seem to be able to draw stacked lines or polygons (attached).

```
plot=ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=Example,aes(colour = value), size=0.8)  + 
  scale_color_viridis(option = "H") 
  plot_gg(plot,multicore=TRUE,width=5,height=5,scale=250)
```

Another option is 3dplot, but the x/y coordinates yield straight lines, while the geodetics are curved polylines.
I have also not found any previous examples of this in R. Any possible solutions?

[image: ArcGIS Pro example]
[image: R example][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yF92.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions. Both involve converting the lines to tightly-spaced points and adding x/y coordinates in GIS.

1. via plot3D:

```
  library(sf)
  Example<-st_read("R/points.shp")
  library("plot3D")
  x=Example$x
  y=Example$y
  z=Example$z
  scatter3D(x, y, z, clab = c("value"), pch = 20, theta = 15, phi=30, expand =0.05, 
            colkey = list(side = 1, length = 0.5))
```

[image]

2. A second working solution is through GRASS GIS/rgrass and m.nviz.image:

```
  execGRASS('m.nviz.image', vline='roads', vline_width=1, vline_color='grey', 
            vpoint='points_3d', vpoint_layer='1', vpoint_size=7, vpoint_width=5, twist=3, 
            position= c(0.65, 1.0), height=1500, perspective=12, zexag=2, 
            output="C:/R/plot.tiff", format='tif', size=c(1200,700), flags = "overwrite")
```

[image]